# SSL illegal key size for client to ASMX service

Tags: java, c#, ssl, https

We have a customer who is having issues uploading files using HTTPS to a ASMX service we host. We've recently changed servers, and in the process changed from Windows Server 2008 to 2012. Since our server moved, the customer has been unable to upload files to us through HTTPS (through HTTP works fine). We have a valid SSL certificate and have tested in various other machines to ensure it's not a general issue, but we can't replicate it at all.

The customer is using a legacy Java application, which is returning the following error:

```
SecurityProvider error generating RSA public key: java.lang.Exception: Illegal key size: (512). Must be > 1024!
```

Does this sound like something we can fix (i.e. does the error imply we are now forcing a 1024 bit key), or does the customer need to fix their legacy application?